# How to have bootstrap grid switch straight from 1 row 3 columns to 3 rows 1 column

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a webpage with a row that contains a button, some text, then another button in 3 columns.  Appearing as:
[image]

When the width of the viewport shrinks it looks like:
[image]

How can I make it so the button, text and other button stack on top of each other, center aligned, when the viewport is smaller, but stay one row when large enough to be accommodated (skipping the 2 columns on one row and one column on a second row stage)?

Current HTML:

```
<div class="container">
              <div class="row justify-content-md-center align-items-center">
                <div class="col text-center">
                  <a class="btn btn-lg btn-adapt btn-dark" href="#">Compare free and paid plans</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 text-center">
                  or
                </div>
                <div class="col text-center">
                  <a class="btn btn-lg btn-adapt btn-dark" href="#">Read our getting started guide</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7j9eodpt/

Comment: I believe that it's because there is no margin between the two buttons. Try adding `my-3` to each of the buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?:

```js
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center align-items-center">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 text-center">
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-adapt btn-dark" href="#">Compare free and paid plans</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 text-center">
      or
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 text-center">
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-adapt btn-dark" href="#">Read our getting started guide</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It was still overflowing for me on col-md-4, I think due to being nested in another container that had pretty wide margins.  But you set me on the right path, "col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4" (with col-lg-1 for the "or") works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Just switch to `col-sm` (or `col-md` if you want it to stack sooner)...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center align-items-center">
        <div class="col-sm text-center">
            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-adapt btn-dark" href="#">Compare free and paid plans</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 text-center"> or </div>
        <div class="col-sm text-center">
            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-adapt btn-dark" href="#">Read our getting started guide</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/fIeulypQp1